# Deploy ASPNET Core (ASPNET 5) application on IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to deploy a ASPNET Core (old ASPNET 5) application to IIS.

I was able to deploy to a new Web Site following [this guide](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). But I want to deploy it to a virtual directory.

I tried to follow the same steps (but using Virtual Directory instead of Web Site), but I was unsuccessful. The page does not respond, and DNX is not launched.

I am using runtime 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Comment: You should get a 503 or a 404 response.
If you get a 503 then make sure you haven't registered HttpPlatformHandler more than once (e.g. in the root site and the VDir).
If you get a 404: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Check if in web.config file in handlers section in aspNetCore handler you have not `directoryPath="*"` statement. If there is just delete it, but only this statement not an entirehandler. Check on image below.

I remember that I had a problem with that.

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2v0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

in my expreience for launch aspnet core project on iis you should try to this steps:

1- dont use source for lunch because iis need web.config so just lunch after publish, publish create a web.config to you

2- be sure that install the core [modules](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0) to your iis

3- dont use shared app pool , create a new one and set Clr version to "No managed code"

i hope this can be useful